# Filtrar un array a través de valores de otro array

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones

Soy bastante nuevo en esto del javascript.
Para practicar básicamente me he dispuesto a crear scripts bobos como filtros y tal en google sheets...

Lo datos que obtengo de la sheet en la que estoy trabajando son dos Arrays del mismo lenght, names y sets, el names[0] se corresponde el sets[0], y así sucesivamente.

Lo que he hecho es un for loop que revise uno por uno cada valor del array names hasta que encuentre un elemento que sea exactamente igual a una variable de una celda de la sheet e inserte el valor del array sets que le corresponda en otro array que luego será puesto en una celda de la sheet.

Por lo que entiendo de momento el problema está en mi if puesto que el valor de objetos no se inserta.

```
function SetFilter() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName('DataBase');
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();


  var Sets = Sheet.getRange(2, 2, LastRow, 2).getValues();
  var Names = Sheet.getRange(2, 1, LastRow, 1).getValues();
  var SelectedName = SS.getSheetByName('SetFilter').getRange('A2').getValues();
  var InsertSets = [];

  for (let NamesCounter = 0; NamesCounter < Names.length; NamesCounter++) {

    if (SelectedName === MatchingName)

      var MatchingName = Names[NamesCounter]

    InsertSets.push(Sets[NamesCounter])

    break
  }
  var InsertRange = SS.getSheetByName('SetFilter').getRange(2, 2, 1, 2);
  InsertRange.setValues(InsertSets);
 
}
```

[image: Arrays]

[image: Filtro]

Comment: Podrías incluir los `json` que estas trabajando?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,. He editado la publicación explicando un poco mejor el "concepto" y he incluido el script entero para que todo sea más sencillo de entender...

Comment: Tal vez sería útil que incluyas una muestra de la hoja de cálculo también.

Comment: Ahí he incluido unas muestras.

La primera imagen incluye los arrays  (la primera columna es Names y la segunda es Sets)

La segunda imagen es de donde tomo el valor de la variable antes elegida y al lado debería insertarse el valor de InsertSets...

el problema es que por alguna razón el for loop continúa loopeando aún cuando ya encontró el valor que es igual a la variable elegida... y al final no inserta nada...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que pude sacar en limpio de tu pregunta, es que necesitas *obtener un registro X de tu array, dependiendo un valor previamente seleccionado*.

Por lo que, todo se simplificaría utilizando **[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)**.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, value: "Goku", type: "Saiyayin" },
  { id: 2, value: "Vegeta", type: "Saiyayin" },
  { id: 3, value: "Piccolo", type: "Namek" },
  { id: 4, value: "Krilin", type: "Humano" }
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, value: "Goku", type: "Saiyayin" },
  { id: 2, value: "Vegeta", type: "Saiyayin" },
  { id: 3, value: "Piccolo", type: "Namek" },
  { id: 4, value: "Krilin", type: "Humano" }
];

const getVal = (character) => {
  let aux = [];
  const index = arr1.findIndex((x) => x.value === character);

  if (index >= 0) {
    aux.push(arr2[index]);
  }
  alert(`Seleccionaste ${JSON.stringify(aux)}`);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="getVal('Piccolo')">Obtener registro</button>
```

Como mencionaste que ambos arreglos contienen los mismos datos, cree dos arrays identicos.
La función `getVal` es la que implementa tu lógica, que se resume en:

- Obtenemos la posición del arreglo que contiene tu elemento seleccionado
- Verificamos que el `index` entregado sea mayor o igual 0, lo que se traduce en que existe un registro concordante; de lo contrario te entregaría un -1.
- *Pusheamos* el objeto dentro de tu arreglo `InsertSets` (o `aux` para este ejemplo) y listo!

Si tienes dudas, acá estaremos.